# Convergence of solutions of $\begin{cases}x' = \sqrt{1/n + x^2} \\ x(0) = 1 \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Discuss the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \varphi_n(t)$ where $\varphi_n$ is a solution of $\begin{cases}x' = \sqrt{1/n + x^2} \\ x(0) = 1 \end{cases}$.

The problem is whether I can apply here the continuous dependence on parameters and  initial conditions since only for $\lambda \ge 0$ I have a guarantee that there is a unique solution by Picard-Lindëlof. However, the domain of the equation is then $D  = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+_0$ which is not open...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at Lemma 3.1 in Jack Hale's book on ordinary differential equations chapter 1. You have a sequence of fields $f_n(t,x)=\sqrt{\frac1n + x^2}$ which converges uniformly in compacts of $\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)$ to $f_0(t,x)=x$. The Lemma guarantees that solutions to 
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=f_n(t,x)\\
x(0)&=1
\end{align}
 converge uniformly in any interval of the form $[a,T]$, $a<0<T$. to the solution of the ode 
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=f_0(t,x)\\
x(0)&=1
\end{align}
That is $\phi_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} e^t$ in any interval $[a,T]$, $a<0<T$.

In general terms, the Lemma can be proved as  as in the (Picard) proof of uniqueness for nice fields $f$. The uniform convergence in compacts of $f_n$ allows to choose the same local bounds in the proof by Picard for all $f_n$. Control on the bound of $\|f_n\|_u$ allows one to invoke Azcoli-Arzela's theorems to any subsequence of $\{\phi_n\}$ of solutions of $\dot{x}=f_n(t,x)$. Each limit being the same.